# Markdown and bibtex to PDF with numbered references

Tags: bibtex, pdf, pandoc, pandoc-citeproc

I have a markdown file with resources in a bibtex file that I compile to a PDF. Is it possible to make the citelinks as numbers (footnote style) instead of e.g. (Jia et al. 2013)? I have seen parameters like `citestyle` and `biblio-style: numeric`, but haven't figured out how to use them. The below doesn't quite work the way I want. How do I tell pandoc to use numbers or plain style.

`pandoc --filter=pandoc-citeproc --standalone --bibliography=mybib.bib mybib.md -o mybib.pdf`

Comment: If you are using `pandoc-citeptoc` you have to select a CSL-style with `--csl`. There are quite a few styles around: [citationstyles.org](https://citationstyles.org). If you want to use `natbib` or `biblatex` you have to use `--natbib` or `--biblatex` instead of `pandoc-citeproc`

Comment: I thought `--natbib` and `--biblatex` were not meant for PDF output!?

Comment: `pandoc-citeproc` is for all formats, `biblatex` and `natbib` are for LaTeX only. This is rather well documented here: https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#citation-rendering